# Generate Maven resources at build time

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Confluence add-on, which is a Maven project. I want to copy/aggregate/download/generate some resources into the src/main/resources directory during the build process. How can I configure Maven to let me run some code during the build process to create these resources?

Comment: `src/main/resources` is supposed for static resources, why would you like to add dynamically generated resources there and not into the project build directory?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use ant during the build. 
Example:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>taskId</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target name="targetName">
         <!-- put some ant code here -->
        </target>
      </configuration>
     <goals>
       <goal>run</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
```